# Alternative to for loop that creates matrix of shifted rows

Tags: r, performance, loops, for-loop, matrix

The following code uses a 10 x 2 matrix, with Index and Price as columns. It then shifts variable Price m times and creates a matrix of 10 x m with the shifted variables. Finally, it appends that matrix to the original data frame. This is a template I run on a large database. If possible, I would like to find an alternative approach to the for loop to improve the code's performance/speed.

```
#Data
df <- data.frame(
  Index = c(1:10),
  Price = c(1221, 1220, 1220, 1217, 1216,  1218 , 1216, 1216, 1217, 1220))

#Define rowShift function
rowShift <- function(x, shiftLen = 1L) { 
  r <- (1L + shiftLen):(length(x) + shiftLen)
  r[r<1] <- NA
  return(x[r])  }

#Pre-allocate variables/matrix for shifted rows
n <- NROW(df$Price)
m <- 5 #how many rows to shift
FwdMatrix <- matrix(nrow = n, ncol = m)
dimnames(FwdMatrix) <- list(rownames(FwdMatrix, do.NULL = FALSE, prefix = ""),colnames(FwdMatrix, do.NULL = FALSE, prefix = "Fwd"))

#Loop to create shifted rows variables
for(i in 1:m) { FwdMatrix[,i ] <- rowShift(df$Price,-i) }
Index <- df$Index
FwdMatrixBis <- cbind(FwdMatrix, Index)
FwdDF <- data.frame(FwdMatrixBis) 
df2 <- merge(df, FwdDF, by = "Index", sort = FALSE)
```

Comment: Like `FwdMatrix <- matrix(unlist(data.table::shift(df$Price, 1L:5L)), ncol=5)`?

Comment: Hell yes! Amazing, thank you. Want to put that as a response so I may check the question as answered?

Comment: Also, would you know if it'd be possible to write "m" instead of "5" as input in your code somehow? Getting an error message when trying that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `shift` from the `data.table` package:

```
library(data.table)
m <- 5
FwdMatrix <- matrix(unlist(shift(df$Price, 1L:m)), ncol=m)
```